# Bash and Regular Expressions to remove tags in a xml file

Tags: xml, regex, bash, unix

I need to resolve a question that has kept me all day trying to resolve it.

I have the following XML file:

```
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p class="subtit">Transporte:</p>
<p>Para transporte desde y hacia el Aeropuerto Internacional Arturo Merino Benítez (fono 56-2-690 19 00) existen diversas empresas que prestan este servicio: buses, minibuses y taxis. Se recomienda contratar transporte autorizado dentro del aeropuerto.</p>

<TXT_accesp>
<p>Climate:</p>
<p>Santiago has a temperate Mediterranean climate with an annual average temperature of 14.5º Celsius. September is the start of spring, the climate is gentle and fresh with highs reaching 28 degrees during the day that drop to 6º C (43º F) to 12º C (54º F) at night.</p>
<p> </p>
<p>Language:</p>
<p>Spanish</p>
<p> </p>
</TXT_accesp>

<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p class="subtit">Transporte:</p>
<p>Para transporte desde y hacia el Aeropuerto Internacional Arturo Merino Benítez (fono 56-2-690 19 00) existen diversas empresas que prestan este servicio: buses, minibuses y taxis. Se recomienda contratar transporte autorizado dentro del aeropuerto.</p>
```

Then I remove all tags `<p> </ p>` without deleting the text that is inside, but only those `<p> </ p>` found **inside the tag** `<TXT_accesp> and </ TXT_accesp>`

I'm doing it with bash as many files will be where I need to replace those tags. What I've done so far is the following:

```
sed -e 's/<TXT_accesp><p>\(.*\)<\/p><\/TXT_accesp>$/\1/g' example.xml
```

The idea is to remove all `<p> </ p>` text or independent if they are not inside, but if you have text not removed. After that, the idea is that you save the changes.

**Can you help me?**

Thirst is not whether the command is indicated or if I combine it with another. In addition, regular expressions do not know if it's correct.

Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to remove the `<p>` and `</p>` tags inside `<TXT_accesp>` and `</ TXT_accesp>` then you can use something like this -

```
sed '/\<TXT_accesp\>/,/\<\/TXT_accesp\>/s@</\?p>@@g' INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: Excellent!

But, if I wanted to also add more tags? or for example set to replace them all name tags TXT_xxx how should I? Something like?? TXT_ .*

Comment: To add more tags you can use the `OR` operand. In `sed` you can use it by escaping the `pipe symbol` (i.e `\|`). You can only add more tabs in the substitution part and they all will get replaced with your replacement portion. For eg. `s@</\?p>\|</\?text>@@g` substitutes `<p>` and `<text>` tags.

Comment: Hello again. I'm not clear why I can only add more tags on the replacement. 

What I need exactly is:`<p>Climate:</p>

<TXT_accesp>
<p>Climate:</p>
<p> </p>
</TXT_accesp>

<TXT_acceng>
<p>Climate:</p>
<p> </p>
</TXT_acceng>

<p>Climate:</p>`

Then, just to find only `<p> </ p>` which are within `<TXTaccesp> </ TXTaccesp>` or `<TXTaccesp> </ TXTaccesp>`

All `<p> </ p>` which is outside those tags should be left the same.

Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: Aah I got you now … you can add more to your existing one by doing `||` before `sed` statement. So in this case it will be `sed '/\<TXT_accesp\>/,/\<\/TXT_accesp\>/||/\<TXT_acceng\>/,/\<\/TXT_acceng\>/s@</\?p>@@g' INPUT_FILE`

Comment: This issue of the regular expressions I have complications. In fact, it still does not work. He gives the following error: "unknown command". When he was just a label worked well, but I added the last thing I spent and that error message appears.

**This is the full code of my script:**

`find /home -type f -name "*.html" -exec sed -i '/\<TXT_accesp\>/,/\<\/TXT_accesp\>/||/\<TXT_acceng\>/,/\<\/TXT_acceng\>/s@</\?p>‌​@@g' {} \;`

I will greatly appreciate your help in order to realize this simple but tangled task.

Comment: This would work `sed -e '/\<TXT_accesp\>/,/\<\/TXT_accesp\>/s@</\?p>@@g' -e '/\<TXT_acceng\>/,/\<\/TXT_acceng\>/s@</\?p>@@g' INPUT_FILE`

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help.

Finally, the code has been as follows:

`find /home -type f -name "*.html" -exec \
    sed -i -e '/<TXT_accesp>/,/<\/TXT_accesp>/s@</\?p>@@g' \
           -e '/<TXT_acceng>/,/<\/TXT_acceng>/s@</\?p>@@g' \
        {} \;`

Comment: Awesome .. sorry about the earlier sample … it needs to have perl type regexes to work. So usually if you want to go with posix style then `-e` is used to add more and more `sed's` expressions. :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use xsh2 for XML processing. It requires well-formed XML, though, so I had to wrap your data into `<root> ... </root>`. Then, I just ran xsh2:

```
open file.xml ;
for //TXT_accesp/p xmove (*|text()) replace . ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: where do we find xsh2? Looks interesting. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Google is your friend :-) You can find it on http://xsh.sourceforge.net or as XML::XSH2 at CPAN (http://cpan.org).

Answer (score 0):

```
is_inside=false
while read -r line; do
        if [[ "$line" =~ "<TXT_accesp>" ]]; then
                is_inside=true
        elif [[ "$line" =~ "</TXT_accesp>" ]]; then
                is_inside=false
        fi 
        if [ $is_inside = true ]; then
                echo $line | sed -e 's/<p>\(.*\)<\/p>$/\1/g'
        else
                echo $line
        fi
done
```